# How do I clear my React web app browser cache?

Tags: reactjs, web, caching, web-applications

We have a React web application that thousands of customers use each month. This application is built using React.js, and deployed/hosted on Firebase. The issue we are having is that when we put out new builds, and deploy to production, some customers are still using an outdated version of the app.

My assumption is that the browser cookies are saved and the old version is cached on their browser. Is there a way to automatically clear/refresh cookies and cache on the browser on EACH page load? This way we ensure the customers are using the **most recent** version of the web app EVERY time they load it up.

Thanks a ton!!